# multiplo de un numero (estructuras de control iterativas)

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles, while

tengo el siguiente problema:
Dados dos números n y m, debes hallar los primeros m multiplos de n.
si m es mayor a 20, SOLO puedes imprimir los primeros 20 múltiplos del número.

la primera parte del problema la resuelvo sin problema pero como hago para cuando m es mayor a 20 me de solo los primeros 20 multiplos?

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
cont = 1
while cont <= m :
    print(cont * n)
    cont = cont + 1
```

muchas gracias.

Comment: Una forma muy simple es usando una sentencia `if` para comparar el valor de `cont` con 20. Si es mayor, sales del bucle usando `break`. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como digo en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/557471/multiplo-de-un-numero-estructuras-de-control-iterativas#comment985072_557471), una forma muy sencilla, dado el código mostrado en la pregunta, es usar una sentencia `if` para comparar el valor de `cont` con 20. Por ejemplo:

```py
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
cont = 1
while cont <= m :
    print(cont * n)
    cont = cont + 1
    if cont > 20:
        break
```

Otra forma sería limitando el valor de `m` desde el momento de obtenerlo, por ejemplo:

```py
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
if m > 20:
    m = 20
cont = 1
while cont <= m :
    print(cont * n)
    cont = cont + 1
```

Otra forma sería usando un bucle `for` y una estructura de tipo `range`. Por ejemplo:

```py
n = int(input())
m = min(20, int(input()))
for i in range(0, m):
    print(n * (i + 1))
```

Por último, y siendo lo más *pythónico* posible, podrías hacerlo con una comprehensión de lista, por ejemplo:

```py
n = int(input())
m = min(20, int(input()))
_ = [print(n * (i + 1)) for i in range(0, m)]
```

Esto imprime en pantalla los múltiplos deseados y la lista generada (tendrá sólo elementos `None`) se almacena en una variable descartable para que no salga impresa en pantalla.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: También solo podría hacer `m = min(20, int(input()))`

Comment: Si, es correcto, muchas gracias

Comment: Mauricio Contreras y Jacobo muchas gracias por sus aportes.De verdad muchas gracias.

Comment: Al principio, pensaba que la comprensión de lista siempre era una buena opción. Ahora se que crear una lista de None solo ocupa memoria y velocidad al cohete

Comment: @DanteS. lo de "ocupar" memoria es realtivo, es decir, siendo que Python trae su propio colector de basura, si no asignas la lista a una variable, será descartada por el mismo ya que no habrá una referencia en memoria a ella, pero si la asignas, obviamente creas una referencia y se mantendrá allí hasta que el ámbito donde existe dicha referencia sea desvinculado. Yo la he asignado únicamente para que no se imprima por pantalla. Saludos

Comment: Peeero, la lista existe durante su creación.

Comment: Que si, que si hombre. Que usarla para este caso de uso es sólo presumir del lenguaje, XD. De todas formas, una lista llena de `None` tampoco es que te vaya a comer toda la memoria, digo yo, y menos en este caso que sólo tiene un máximo de 20 elementos. Saludos

Comment: Ahhh entiendo. Aun así vendría bien aclararlo. En este caso no es muuuuy importante, pero es bueno tenerlo en cuenta para cuando se trabaje con muchos más datos.